# List of table affect when a order is placed

Tags: magento2, orders

Need to know all the table that are **affected** when a `order` is placed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

these table affects when a order is placed.

```
sales_order
sales_order_address
sales_order_grid
sales_order_item
sales_order_payment
quote
quote_item

sales_invoice
sales_invoice_comment
sales_invoice_grid
sales_invoice_item

sales_shipment
sales_shipment_comment
sales_shipment_grid
sales_shipment_item
sales_shipment_track

customer_address_entity
customer_address_entity_datetime
customer_address_entity_decimal
customer_address_entity_int
customer_address_entity_text
customer_address_entity_varchar
customer_entity
customer_entity_datetime
customer_entity_decimal
customer_entity_int
customer_entity_text
customer_entity_varchar
customer_grid_flat
customer_log
customer_log
customer_visitor
persistent_session
wishlist
wishlist_item
wishlist_item_option
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here the list of tables which are affected when an order is placed:**

```
salesrule_coupon_usage
sales_order
sales_order_address
sales_order_aggregated_created
sales_order_aggregated_updated
sales_order_grid
sales_order_item
sales_order_payment
sales_order_status
sales_order_status_history
sales_order_tax
sales_order_tax_item
sales_sequence_meta
sales_sequence_profile
sales_shipping_aggregated
sales_shipping_aggregated_order

cataloginventory_stock_status
```

Comment: there are lot of other table start with 'sales' are found . What about shipment and invoice

Comment: there are tables with sales_invoice_* and sales_shipment_*